# Any repercussions to requiring the same file twice in node.js?

Tags: node.js

Will I run into any problems if I require the same file twice?

```
require('myclass.js');
require('myclass.js');
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Absolutely none.  Modules are [cached](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching) the first time they are loaded so the second call is just a no-op.

Comment: Unless the module does something on require, which is probably bad practice anyways..

Comment: @Knownasilya The code in the required module is only run the first time `require` is called, or were you referencing something else?

Comment: Even if you have an IIFE in your module? So it caches the result and gives you that on subsequent calls?

Comment: @Knownasilya Right, the module's `module.exports` object created in the first call is cached and also returned in the second call.  There's nothings special about IIFEs in this regard.

Answer (score 3):

I discovered a caveat, resulting from the fact that requiring twice is a no-op: requiring a file, mutating the object returned by that file, and requiring the file again will not undo the mutations.

Example:

```
let path;
path = require('path');
console.log(path.asdf);

path.asdf = 'foo';
console.log(path.asdf);

path = require('path');
console.log(path.asdf);
```

This produces the following output:

```
undefined
foo
foo
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you shouldn't run into any problems. The module system node uses won't have global problems, if that was your question. The real question is... why would u want to require twice?

Comment: I'm dynamically including files so there is a chance I may require the same one twice

Comment: Are you trying to load modules dynamically depending on the outcome of a function? If so here is what I think will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914751/loading-node-js-modules-dynamically-based-on-route

Comment: I would like to require the same file twice, because the file itself includes a function, that I'm mocking in my tests. However I have different tests which mock the function differently, and it doesn't work because the file can only be included once.

Comment: @DavidTorres, you can use jest.isolateModules for it, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45571816/reset-single-module-with-jest