# Reset single module with Jest

Tags: node.js, jestjs, commonjs

`jest.resetModules()` clears the require cache for all modules but is there a way to clear it for just a single module? Can't use `require.cache` as Jest appears to bypass it.

I'm testing a Node module which is stateful (i.e. it relies on the fact that multiple calls to `require` return the same instance). For my test I need to reset the state of the module to test different scenarios. `jest.resetModules()` works but then I need to re-`require` some other mocked modules which didn't need to be reset.

Comment: Looking through the source this isn't possible at the moment. [resetModules](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/master/packages/jest-runtime/src/index.js#L420-L440) completely blanks `_moduleRegistry` and you have no access to it from inside the testing context. I'd say it needs a new method adding to the context that can remove single modules from the registry. I'd suggest opening and issue on the [repo](https://github.com/facebook/jest) and hopefully they will be able to update jest with this functionality.

Comment: If it makes sense, you can isolate your stateful module and test it with `resetModules()` on its own.

Comment: Maybe you can load the single module like this: `jest.mock( '../moduleName',  () => { const myModule = importFresh('/path/to/module') },  {virtual: true}, );`? This would allow you to load a fresh copy of the module, thus, effectively resetting the module for your test purposes. `importFresh` comes from https://github.com/sindresorhus/import-fresh

Comment: Following this thread https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/6174 seems that it's still an open issue/improvement. Also there is an open PR for scoped module initialization. Check here: https://github.com/facebook/jest/pull/6701 However anything mature enough and ready to use for now...

Comment: Jest creates its own `require` hook this is mainly used to keep the global require cache clean and avoid side effects. From what you are doing it sounds like you just need to mock the module you want to use and then make sure you clear it at the end of the `describe` block, you should never leave mock modules laying around for other tests to use.

If you are setting up and tearing down your mocks correctly you shouldn't run into this issue. Can you provide a better example?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As explained in the question, `jest.resetModules()` resets the module cache, which is useful your module keeps some local state and you want to get rid of that state between tests.

The problem with resetModules is that it resets everything but sometimes you want only some of the modules to be reset.

Since Jest 24 you can now use the [`jest.isolateModules`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestisolatemodulesfn) to do this.

Let's say you have a module that keeps state:

module.js

```
exports.a = 1
exports.add = function (a) {
  return exports.a += a;
}
```

module.test.js

```
test('adds 1 to counter', () => {
  jest.isolateModules(() => {
    const myModule = require('./module');
    expect(myModule.add(1)).toBe(2);
    expect(myModule.add(1)).toBe(3);
  });
});

test('adds 2 to counter', () => {
  jest.isolateModules(() => {
    const myModule = require('./module');
    expect(myModule.add(2)).toBe(3);
    expect(myModule.add(2)).toBe(5);
  });
});
```

Basically with after every jest.isolateModules() call, the next time the module is required it will be have a fresh state.

Comment: can we get an expanded example of this? This is similar to the jest documentation which doesn't clearly state what is happening or how to use it imo

Comment: agree with @ElFik. can anyone expand on this answer?

Comment: Extended the answer with a better example.

Comment: Interesting note, when using `jest.isolateModules()` or `jest.resetModules()`,  the test file doesn't count as the `module.parent` for rmodules required directly from the test file. Other files still have the correct `module.parent`.

Answer (score 9):

An example of mocking modules (with factories) for some tests, and restoring for others within a test file

```
describe("some tests", () => {
  let subject;

  describe("with mocks", () => {
    beforeAll(() => {
      jest.isolateModules(() => {
        jest.doMock("some-lib", () => ({ someFn: jest.fn() })); // .doMock doesnt hoist like .mock does when using babel-jest
        subject = require('./module-that-imports-some-lib');
      });
    });

    // ... tests when some-lib is mocked
  });

  describe("without mocks - restoring mocked modules", () => {
    beforeAll(() => {
      jest.isolateModules(() => {
        jest.unmock("some-lib");
        subject = require('./module-that-imports-some-lib');
      });
    });

    // ... tests when some-lib is NOT mocked

  });
});
```