# Reset specific modules in JEST instead of all modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm looking to do something similar that's posed in the following question:
[how to reset module imported between tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989643/how-to-reset-module-imported-between-tests)

This works, however it resets ALL modules. I only want/need to reload a single module and can't figure out how to accomplish it.

[`JEST.isolateModules`](https://jestjs.io/docs/26.x/jest-object#jestisolatemodulesfn) seems like the solution but i haven't been able to get it to work.

Anyone have any examples of reloading just a single module in a JEST test?

Comment: Found the answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45571816/reset-single-module-with-jest/54791921#54791921