# Require Dynamically in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs, node-modules, commonjs

I am working on a CLI package inside a monorepo that has a command called `buildX`:
Goes through several directories, try to `require` a module that exist in some files withing those directories.

So basically I will try to do something like:

```
buildX --source ./somewhere --target ./somewhere/else
```

And it should do some operations with those modules in somewhere and save it in target.

**The problem is:**
If i have:

```
* - somewhere
*   | - index.js
*
*somewhere else
```

Index.js:

```
import { coolFunction } from 'cool-library';

export default coolFunction({some: object, generated: dynamically })
```

While doing `require('./somewhere/index.js')`, there is an exception: It cannot find the module in the specified path. This is because when executing __dirname, the path that appears there is the path where the `bin` is stored, instead of the one where it is executed.

How could I require index.js in a dynamic way? I tried with `SystemJS`, also with eval, also with `dynamic-import-support`.

I just want to be able to execute the index.js export default.

Any suggestion or solution is totally welcome! Thanks in advance

Comment: Try this instead.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914751/loading-node-js-modules-dynamically-based-on-route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution based on [ESLint](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/blob/master/lib/util/module-resolver.js)'s library. The have a util function that helps to import the configuration files on the flight from the current workspace instead of using `__dirname`.

For the problems that people may find after requiring successfully, like ES6 imports or any other feature not supported by your node version, you could use [babel-register](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/babel-register/) to build your modules on the flight instead of pre-building them.