# Is it possible to dynamically import a node module?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I would like to know if it is possible to dynamically import a module installed via npm install.

Something like:

```
import("{ AsyncStorage } from react-native ???").then((module) => {
  // do something with module
});
```

All the examples I found so far are just importing self written ES modules...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914751/loading-node-js-modules-dynamically-based-on-route

Comment: require is awesome but I prefer to stick with ES module imports. BTW I am not in a nodejs environment

Comment: In which enviroment do you want to do that `import`? client side, server side, in react, ... ? What tool do you use to compose your project?

Comment: I am trying to reuse some modules of a legacy react-native application in a react project. I am using webpack to bundle the react application

Comment: It should either be `import("react-native").then(({AsyncStorage: module}) => …)` or `import("react-native/AsyncStorage").then(module => …)`

Comment: What does the dynamic import have to do with the fact the module was installed via npm?

Comment: The problem is that, while doing dynamic import with a module installed via _npm_ , webpack seems to fail to load other files imported by the module I am importing. Example with _react-native_ (using your first proposition): it imports react-native but complains about any other file imported by _react-native_, like _WebView_ for example

Comment: Please state whether you intend to do this in node.js or in a browser environment.  ECMAScript Modules are still experimental in node.js.  Additionally, dynamic imports are still only at stage 3: [proposal-dynamic-import](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-dynamic-import) and may not have support in whereever you are implementing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do it like this

```js
// With normal promises
import('react-native').then(({ AsyncStorage }) => {
 // Do something with the module
})

// Async/await (You must add this code inside of an async function or use ecmascript module code)
const { AsyncStorage } = await import('react-native')
// Do something with the module
```

Answer (score -3):

The real dynamically import in `node_modules` based on Environment variables ([PD_PLATFORM](https://github.com/tagspaces/tagspaces-common/blob/develop/packages/dynamic-packages-loading/index.js#L95)) or command line parameter is implemented here:

https://github.com/tagspaces/tagspaces-common/tree/develop/packages/dynamic-packages-loading

usage in npm script: `npx @tagspaces/dynamic-packages-loading ./ -p node` -> this will install in `node_modules` `nodeDependencies` from [package.json](https://github.com/tagspaces/tagspaces-common/blob/develop/packages/dynamic-packages-loading/sample/package.json)

`npx @tagspaces/dynamic-packages-loading ./ -p web` -> install `webDependencies`

This install script will copy index.js after `npm install` based on `process.env.PD_PLATFORM` https://github.com/tagspaces/tagspaces-common/blob/develop/packages/platforms/package.json#L8