# Ways to plug new React Components automatically aka "pluggable extensions"

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, flux, react-context

I am looking for design ideas and/or solution examples on how to achieve following:

There is React app (client-server) with a component store (Reflux-based) that holds React ref. to registered components and metadata that is used in app to incorporate them by React(e.g. consider as plugglable widgets).

I am looking the way how to **load modules or get registered** newly installed packages "extension" (e.g. @myapp/extensionA) in the main app start w/o precise listing them anywhere and populate component store index, say, "extension" has config.json holding all metadata necessary for registration/load.

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914751/loading-node-js-modules-dynamically-based-on-route

Comment: @MohitMutha, it does partially answer (I have already tried the approach mentioned earlier), however, it works only for server side node modules, it does not solve two things: a. the modules are not available on client side (as client bundle does have them) b. how to make package-based extensions (not looking into custom DIR)