# require() not working in module type nodejs script

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

In my **package.json** file I've specified that my `nodejs` app is of type `module`, because if I do not do that, it seems that I can not use `import` statements. This is how it looks like now:

```
{
  "name": "...",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "....",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "...."
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.17.15"
  },
  "type": "module"
}
```

But if I add the `"type": "module"` to my **package.json** file, I can't use `require` statements anymore, because I get a `ReferenceError: require is not defined` error.

If I remove the `"type": "module"` line from **package.json**, and rewrite all of my imports to requires, everything works without an error.

I can't seem to find any indication, that `import` and `require` can not be mixed or used together in the same script, am I missing something here, or I am having some other bug? How could I resolve to use these two kind of statements in the same script?

*Why* I would need this, is because I want to `require` some config files based on dynamic paths, and only if the files exists, which I think I can not do with `import`.

**DISCLAIMER:** I am rather new to nodejs server side programming, so it is possible that I am approaching this situation very wrongly, if that's the case, please advice me something, based on the *Why* I've mentioned above.

**NOTE:** I am running this node script from the server terminal, and not from the browser.

Comment: Have you checked out this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/10915442/2313097

Comment: Sorry I missed the part about config files initially. I've updated my answer now, but I think you figured it out by following the `import()` link or something given you'd already accepted the answer. :-)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> But if I add the `"type": "module"` to my `package.json` file, I can't use `require` statements anymore, because I get a `ReferenceError: require is not defined error`.

Right. It's either/or. Either you use ESM (JavaScript modules, type = "module") **or** you use CJS (CommonJS-like Node.js native modules, `require`).

But there **is** some interoperability between them. For instance, in an ESM module you can [`import` CJS modules](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#import-statements), and you can use [`createRequire`](https://nodejs.org/api/module.html#modulecreaterequirefilename) to create a `require` function to use to load CJS modules.

> Why I would need this, is because I want to `require` some config files based on dynamic paths, and only if the files exists, which I think I can not do with `import`.

You can still do that while using `type="module"`. You have a few options:

1. If these "config" files are JavaScript, you can use `createRequire`:

   ```
   import { createRequire } from "module";
   const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);
   const yourData = require("./config.js");
   ```
2. If these config files are JSON, you can use the currently-experimental support for [importing JSON modules](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#json-modules). Since you said you want to allow for files not existing, you'd want to use dynamic `import()` rather than static `import` declarations:

   ```
   let config = /*...defaults...*/;
   try {
       config = await import("./config.json", { assert: { type: "json" } });
   } catch (error) {
       // ...the file didn't exist or wasn't valid JSON...
   }
   ```
3. Or if (again) they're JSON, you can go old school: use `readFile` and `JSON.parse`. :-)

Comment: okay, that seems to solve my issue, just a quick follow up question. It seems, that import does not want to allow me to import a pure JSON file (with `require` it worked). Should I wrap my config file as a javascript file, and export the config object, or is there a way to make import work with JSON files? Scracth this, you already answered my question:)

Comment: @AdamBaranyai - I have? Good. :-) I've also just added a link to `createRequire`, which may be useful for your config files.

Comment: well, partly:) I tought I hit gold with `readFile`, but then I understood that it is dependent on the `fs` module.:) Is there any way, to import a `.json` file, without using any additional module or plugin for the job?:) with pure `import` statements?:) I am yet to check out `createRequire`, so maybe I will find an asnwer there, but in any case, I still ask:)

Comment: @AdamBaranyai - You can't `import` JSON *yet*, but that's being standardized and it will happen; [details](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_experimental_json_modules). Until then, yes, `createRequire` is what you'd do, basically exactly what they show [here](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_commonjs_json_and_native_modules): 1. `import` `createRequire` from `'module'`. 2. Create the `require` function using `createRequire` passing in `import.meta.url`. 3. Use that `require` function to import the JSON. I've added an example to the answer.

Comment: That works great.  But unfortunately, when I try to import/require a file that *itself* uses the "import" statement, I get that warning again for the imported/required file.  I don't want to rename the imported/required file to ".mjs" because it's a large project and there are a lot of dependent files that use the file.  Is there a way to mark an imported/file as a "module" via something like the ""type: module" statement in package.json, but for files imported/required by the project?

Comment: @RobertOschler - Usually those will be part of a package, which will have its own `package.json`, which will have the `type`. If you have an individual file you have to do this with in a module with `"type": "commonjs"` (or no `type`), that's a really, really unusual situation. I had hoped dynamic `import()` to work, but it doesn't. I don't think you have a lot of options other than renaming it, migrating the whole project over to ESM, or putting that file in its own package with its own `package.json`.

Comment: tried the 'createRequire' thing.. gives me this error:
`Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: 
require() of ES modules is not supported.`

Comment: @johnktejik - Right. `createRequire` is (as I say above) for using CJS modules in ESM, not using ESM modules in ESM. For that, use an `import` statement (or an dynamic `import()` expression).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder for me, the reason to use cjs in my ESM files is simple, I need to use [debugjs](https://github.com/debug-js/debug) but it still uses cjs and that is how I found your answer here.

Answer (score 2):

Usually you need Babel to transpile your Node.js code that uses ES Modules.

But if you don't want to use Babel: ES Modules is experimental feature of latest Node.js.

You need 3 things:

1. latest Node.js
2. Add "type": "module" to the package.json
3. Add experimental flag when running node.js `node --experimental-modules app.js`

Comment: There's no need for Babel when using modules on Node.js.

Comment: As I said ES Modules is experimental feature: https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_ecmascript_modules

Comment: While it's true they're marked experimental, there's no need for Babel to use ESM on Node.js. They aren't even behind a flag anymore in v13. I'm a bit surprised the docs still say Experimental, actually. That probably relates to the ongoing work improving interoperability, but ESM import of CJS modules works just fine, so...

Answer (score 1):

```
import { createRequire } from 'node:module';

const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply